# Ruby regex for two words present in a string in any order

Tags: ruby, regex

How do you write a regex to match if any two words are present in a string, in any order?

Ie, I'm trying to write a regex that would find any string with "reset" and "password" in it, case insenstive. So, these should match:

- Reset password
- Password reset
- You reset your password
- Your password reset request
- Your password has been reset

And these should not match

- password
- reset
- password changed
- account reset

The closest I got was: `/(password|reset)/`, but that finds every case, and when I tried `(password|reset){2}` it didn't match any. Testing this out on [rubular](http://rubular.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try

```
(password.*reset|reset.*password)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. 7 minutes until SO will let me accept :)

Comment: I'd say something like `(\bpassword\b.*\breset\b)|(\breset\b.*\bpassword\b)`, so that 'reset' would be expected after a word break, and e.g. 'preset' won't match.

Comment: @9000 your example won't match `password reset`, you're missing some `?` but you've got a good point

Comment: 1. This will incorrectly match strings that include `passwordderivebytes` or `areset`. 2. This will incorrectly not match `PASSWORD`.

Comment: @alestanis: my code does match 'password reset'; I don't dare post untested code on SO.

Answer (score 7):

With zero-width positive look-ahead assertion, you can write it as following forms:

```
/(?=.*\breset\b)(?=.*\bpassword\b)/i
```

After the first assertion is processed, its matching position is not changed and is still the beginning of the string. After then, ruby processes the second assertion.

Note that the second part is not always necessary in assertion form in this case. following code works just as you intended.

```
/(?=.*\breset\b).*\bpassword\b/i
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more elegant to not insist in doing it with one regex, but do two:

```
string =~ /\bpassword\b/i and string =~ /\breset\b/i
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @alestanis and @sawa for the regex, but wouldn't it make intent clearer if you went with a simple `include?`, e.g

```
(str.downcase.include? 'password') && (str.downcase.include? 'reset')
```

My $0.02

Comment: I agree regexp may not be the best answer here, but note that the two include tests can fail in a subtle way in the more general case if the two words overlap.  If the words were 'password' and 'surpass', this test would answer true for str containing 'surpassword'.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution for an arbitrary number of words:

```
def match_all? str, words
  words.all? {|w| str =~ /\b#{ Regexp.quote w }\b/i }
end

match_all? 'Your password reset request', %w{password reset}
```